# How to use TargetField property of asp:menu control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table in sql server 2008 that has all the information about my option menus.
And i am using `<asp:Menu>` control to show option menus in my web site with data binding from that table.In that table i have a field called Target.Values in this field are

> _blank , _parent , _search , _self , _top

this values describes how to open that form.This field is linked with Target property of `<asp:menu>` control.But it's not working.Can any one tell me how to use this property on data bind `<asp:menu>` control.

Comment: Hi ashish, at what time are you binding your target to the menu? Look at the [pagelifecycle events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Thanks.
I were solved this problem by changing the name of Target field in my data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved by changing the name of Target field in my data source.